# mule Invalid content was found starting with element file:inbound-endpoint

Tags: mule, mule-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd">

     <file:connector name="ABCFile" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
     <flow name="abc">
      <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="ABCQuartz" repeatInterval="5000"  responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="ABCQuartz" doc:name="ABC" repeatCount="2">
        <quartz:event-generator-job groupName="creativeworld" jobGroupName="creativeworld">
            <quartz:payload>Creative World Quartz Scheduler.</quartz:payload>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Python">
        <scripting:script engine="jython"/>
    </scripting:component>

    <set-payload value="${COMMAND_PATH}#[' ']${DB_NAME}${OUTPUT_FILE}${URL}" doc:name="Transmission Commands"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payload]#[' -outputpath ']${OUTPUT_FILE}${FILE_NAME}-#[server.dateTime.format('${DATETIME_FORMAT}')]${FILE_TYPE}" doc:name="Output Config"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Display Output"/>
    <invoke object-ref="transmission" method="invoke" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String" methodArguments="#[payload]" name="transmissionAPI"/>
    <logger message="Report generated" level="INFO" doc:name="Display Output"/>

     <!-- Line 38--><file:inbound-endpoint path="${OUTPUT_FILE}" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="ABCFile" doc:name="File">
                <file:file-to-string-transformer/>
                <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt"/>
            </file:inbound-endpoint>

    ....
    </flow>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

error:

```
ERROR 2014-04-30 16:58:37,908 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'file:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":legacy-abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-info-mapping}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at ....org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)
INFO  2014-04-30 16:58:37,913 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'CreativeWorld' never started, nothing to dispose of
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'file:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":legacy-abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-info-mapping}' is expected.
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:219)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 38 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/kbekur/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/CreativeWorld/creativeworld.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'file:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":legacy-abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-info-mapping}' is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use an inbound-endpoint in the middle of your flow. If you need to read a file mid flow take a look at the mule requester module: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester